# jquery: Passing this to child function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:

```
$('element.selector').live("click", function (){
    run_some_func ();
});

$('element.selector2').live("click", function (){
    run_some_func ();
});
```

Now in the function I need to use $(this):

```
function run_some_func () {
    $(this).show();
}
```

How do I get the function to know that $(this) is element.selector that is clicked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/call) function to change the context (set the `this` keyword) on the function you want to execute:

```
$('element.selector').live("click", function (){
  run_some_func.call(this); // change the context of run_some_func
});

function run_some_func () {
  // the this keyword will be the element that triggered the event
}
```

And if you need to pass some arguments to that function, you can:

```
run_some_func.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3); // call run_some_func(arg1,arg2,arg3)
                                            // and change the context (this)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you pass $(this) to your function such that:

```
$('element.selector').live("click", function (){
        run_some_func ($(this));
});
```

..and then

```
run_some_func(obj){
    obj.do_something();
})
```